# Can I change JIRA issue status based on a Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jira

Can I change JIRA issue status based on a Jenkins build? via jenkinsfile. please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jira steps plugin, or you can use Jira API.

E.g. with Jira steps:

```
withEnv(['JIRA_SITE=your_site']) {
    def issue_key = 'MY-12345'
    def result = jiraGetIssue idOrKey: issue_key, failOnError:false
    // you can now expore the issue

    // when you want to change the status, it's called "transition"
    def transition_to_closed_jira_id = 88 // you need to find out your ID
 
    def transitionInput = [ transition: [ id: transition_to_closed_jira_id ] ]
    jiraTransitionIssue idOrKey: issue_key, input: transitionInput
```

Comment: Thank you so much... need to configure status as well.. How can i change status from jenkins ?

Comment: stage ("Transition issue")
        {
            steps {
                script {
                    def transitionInput = [transition: [id: 'MSDP-198']]
     def comment = [ body: 'Build successfully completed' ]
     jiraAddComment idOrKey: 'MSDP-198', input: comment, site: 'JIRA'
                   
     
     
                }
              }
            }                 # this is my current code